# How to install fancyimpute on Anaconda?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

... since I am not able to find `fancyimpute` on https://anaconda.org/search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have not tried it (on windows), but as this package is on PyPI, usually

```
pip install fancyimpute
```

does work.

Comment: (it's on Linux) Is this installing fancyimpute **only** in the respective conda environment?

Comment: @Make42 Sorry, I don't know how conda environments work on Linux, and if `pip` is even aware of them. If they are build on top of virtualenv then it will install in the active virtualenv and `sudo pip install ...` will install it globally. You could just try it and study the log output. You can uninstall with `pip uninstall ...` if something is not as expected.

Comment: Ok, I tried to do it like this and it seems to have worked. However: Does fancyimpute require tensorflow?

Comment: Tensorflow is not listed as a requirement in the `setup.py` or mentioned in the README, so probably not.

Comment: I was asked to install tensorflow - it gave me an error message otherwise. I did and it worked. However, now my script throws `Failed to enable GUI event loop integration for 'qt5'` ... `
ImportError: dlopen: Cannot load further objects with static TLS`. What to do?

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple virtual Python environments on your Anaconda, and you want to install *fancyimpute* for one of them, let's call it virtual environmen **py36**, you can do it in the following way:

1. Open terminal, activate py36 using:

   source activate py36
   [image]
2. Under the activated virtual environment, install *fancyimpute*

   pip install fancyimpute
3. Go to Anaconda, in environment py36 page, click Update index, and search *fancyimpute* for the installed, you should see it successfully installed:
   [image]

Comment: This is the actual response to the OP's question. +1 for the `activate` and final double-check